# Dynamic/Dependent Dropdown List Without Apps Scripts

Tags: google-sheets

I didn't want to use Apps Scripts at first because I was too *lazy* to learn it but now I find it Way more fun to try and wrok around the limitations of using formulas only.

**PROBLEM:**
So I'm trying to do is to make a Dynamic/Dependent Dropdown List without Using Apps Scripts.
[image]

**SOLUTION:**
Using `INDEX` To Change the `C` Column based on `A2`'s Value, And make `B2` Dropdown list from `C:C`
[image]

**SOLUTION's PROBLEM:**
So the plan is to make these Dynamic/Dependent Dropdown List in every **Row**, Thus needing a Column for every row.

**SOLUTION's PROBLEM's SOLUTION:**
Using `TRANSPOSE` we can make the list change from `Vertical` to `Horizontal`
[image]
THIS WORKS GRRRRRRREAT, this means that each row will have its own list on the same row **AND** if the list becomes longer, the `TRANSPOSE` function will add columns by it self as needed... but there's a small teeny tiny pet peeve with it.

**SOLUTION's PROBLEM's SOLUTION's PET PEEVE:**
So I want the sheet to look good, I don't want the data holder cells to show, so I can simply hide the columns... **BUT** if the list gets longer, it will add columns and they won't be hidden
[image: Using TRANSPOSE]

**SOLUTION's PROBLEM's SOLUTION's PET PEEVE's SOLUTION:**
I found that if you group the columns, it gives you a little button at the top that if you click it then it will hide all the columns in the group, And if you includ the last column in your sheet in the group, then any new columns will be added to that group.
[image]

...... Okay last one I swear.

**SOLUTION's PROBLEM's SOLUTION's PET PEEVE's SOLUTION's PET PEEVE:**
It's true that it will group any new column will be added to the group, **BUT** it won't hide them.
[image]
If you just double click the `-/+` Button then it will hide them... okay I lied about it being the last one.

**SOLUTION's PROBLEM's SOLUTION's... Problem....... ah who cares**
Having the columns grouped does make it easier to hide any new columns, but i'm not looking to make the manual easier, I want to fully automat it... also I hate the big bar that's always there when there's a grouped columns.

**Unrelated Fun Fact**: did you know that using the comment function returns a `0`? I didn't... 
so `isblank` in `=isblank(J20 + N("This is a comment To say that J20 is indeed blank"))` returns `FALSE`

**TL;DR** I'm looking for a way to auto hide any new columns created after column `D` for example **OR** use another cleaner way to make Dynamic/Dependent Dropdown List without Using Apps Scripts.

Comment: Hello @omar - nice process. Options you may have without code would be to add a bunch of empty hidden columns, so you don't need to keep hiding them. Or what I usually do is to use an auxiliary sheet that has those rows you're creating

Comment: huh... it's that simple... I really need a rubber duck man.